# SAP Custom Fiori Client (iOS) integration for Intune - Blocked by CA rule because of unauthorized browser

Tags: azure, sap-fiori, intune

I would like to integrate SAP custom Fiori Client into Microsoft Intune.
I generate the cordova project with SAP Kapsel SDK for iOS, do the needed adaptions  (e.g. fioriURL) in xCode, sign it for enterprise distribution and wrap it with the Intune wrapping tool.
CA rules, App protection policy and App configuration policy are all set correctly.

I published the internal URL of the backend system via the Azure AD Webapplication proxy and it is reachable via Intune Managed Browser / Edge without any issues.

When starting the app it leads me to ADFS authentication which is succesful but before getting to the login page for the SAP system, following error appears:
[Cant get there from here. The current browser is not supported, please use Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer to acccess this application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcQ4.png)

I checked it with Chrome for iOS and got the same error. Obviously Conditional Access rules only allow certain browser, but I could not find a way to change that.
Following link stated that a potential solution can be to change the parameter for InAppBrowser.open / window.open calls to "_system". Considering that a lot of cordova plugins use this functionality I do not want to change that in the plugins.
[how to open a link in the Intune Managed browser.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b01774c-dd09-4f01-ad31-54c9b873e599/how-to-open-a-link-in-the-intune-managed-browser?forum=microsoftintuneprod)

I am searching for a solution to either change Conditional Access rules to allow different browsers or adapt the custom fiori client in a way that the respective browsers are used.

Thanks for all of your input :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft docu https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-configuration-managed-browser
it says the following:

Conditional Access for protected browsers

The Managed Browser is now an approved client app for Conditional Access. This means that you can restrict mobile browser access to Azure AD-connected web apps where users can only use the Managed Browser, blocking access from any other unprotected browsers such as Safari or Chrome. This protection can be applied to Azure resources like Exchange Online and SharePoint Online, the Office portal, and even on-premises sites that you have exposed to external users via the Azure AD Application Proxy.
To restrict Azure AD-connected web apps to use the Intune Managed Browser on mobile platforms, you can create an Azure AD Conditional Access policy requiring approved client applications.

1. In the Azure portal, select Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Conditional access > New policy.
2. Next, select Grant from the Access controls section of the blade.
3. Click Require approved client app.
4. Click Select on the Grant blade. This policy must be assigned to the cloud apps that you want to be accessible to only the Intune Managed Browser app.

Please check if above feature is turned on on Azure side.
This may be the reason that only Edge or Intune browser are allowed to access the page.
According to the Azure doc above it seems this was turned on by someone. 
Otherwise you might also want to contact Microsoft for support on this.